# How to avoid code duplication using JAXB with container-like elements with a similar structure

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

**The Situation**

I'm using MOXy's JAXB implementation to work with a large XML document whose schema has many similiar complex types. Specifically, there are about two dozen types that act as list wrapper elements with the following structure:

```
<ITEMS attr1="X" attr2="Y">
  <ITEM>...</ITEM>
  ...
  <EXTENSION/>
<ITEMS>
```

For each of these list-wrapper-like elements, the name changes and the list element being contained changes. However, the attributes (which are all optional) and the single EXTENSION element (also optional) are always present. Here's an example of uses of two of the types:

```
<ROLES visible="false">
  <ROLE type="X"/>
  <ROLE type="Y"/>
</ROLES>

<PAYMENTS visible="true">
  <PAYMENT>
    <PAYEENAME>Joe</PAYEENAME>
  </PAYMENT>
  <EXTENSION>
    <SOMETHING>Here</SOMETHING>
  </EXTENSION>
</PAYMENTS>
```

**The Question**

I would like to avoid code duplication since the only thing changing between these elements is the name and the one-or-more elements it contains. What is the best way to do this?

I can only see two possible solutions.

**1**

Creating a concrete class using generics to indicate the object type to be used in the collection that changes. Then using MOXy's external OX mappings to indicate how any individual use of the class should be serialized. Something like:

```java
public class GenericContainer<T> {
    @XmlAttribute
    protected Boolean visibile;
    @XmlElement(name = "Extension")
    protected Extension extension;

    // OX Mappings done in external meta file
    protected List<T> items;
    ...
}
```

While I like this option, it doesn't appear to be possible to redefine a class's OX mappings on a per-use basis.

**2**

Creating a base class without the List property, and then creating one concrete class for each custom wrapper element. This solution definitely works, but I'll end up with about two dozen near-identitical classes.

Is either #1 possible or is there a better way to handle this that I haven't thought of?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class GenericContainer {

private Boolean visible;
private Object extension;
private List<Object> nodes;

@XmlAttribute
public Boolean isVisible() {
    return visible;
}

public void setVisible(Boolean visible) {
    this.visible = visible;
}

@XmlElement(name="EXTENSION")
public Object getExtension() {
    return extension;
}

public void setExtension(Object extension) {
    this.extension = extension;
}

@XmlAnyElement
public List<Object> getNodes() {
    return nodes;
}

public void setNodes(List<Object> nodes) {
    this.nodes = nodes;
}

}
```

And to read the XML instance

```
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("jaxbtest1");
    Unmarshaller um = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(new File("src/test1.xml"));
    Node node = doc.getFirstChild();

    JAXBElement<GenericContainer> jaxbE = um.unmarshal(node, GenericContainer.class);

    GenericContainer gc = jaxbE.getValue();
    Boolean vis = gc.isVisible();
    Element ext = (Element)gc.getExtension();
    for(Object o : gc.getNodes()) {
        Element listItem = (Element)o;
    }
```

But is code duplication really important? If your schema has a common extension base for the list container types and you are using xjc why avoid distinct classes? After all the idea behind JAXB is having a value class for each unique complex type.

If you can craft general purpose logic that handles similar but distinct XML types and don't want an large number of Java classes you could switch to StAX.

Comment: The example doesn't really fit what I'm looking for, unless I'm missing something. It wouldn't really let me bind list elements to JAXB annotated classes, since the unmarshaller would turn everything into org.w3c.dom.Element objects. Going the other way would a little less awkard, but has no type safety.

Comment: To your question about code duplication, you're right, it's not terribly important. I just really hate doing it. I ended up going down the route of having 30+ near-identical classes, though I wasn't ecstatic about it. The ideal situation would have been to create my own custom java.util.Collection class with generics support, but that seems to be impossible at this point.